# I by mistakenly hit in cmd, npm install in already created app, instead of npm start. Will there be any issue? Can I go ahead without worry?

Tags: node.js, npm

```
D:\SUDARSHAN\BUYERSELLER\buyerseller>npm install
npm WARN tsutils@3.17.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\jest-haste-map\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.2 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\watchpack-chokidar2\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

audited 1663 packages in 6.38s

59 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 4982 low severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

D:\SUDARSHAN\BUYERSELLER\buyerseller>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm install` installs all dependencies of that specific application. For any node project that has dependencies this usually is required to run in order for the application to work. I recommend that you read guides like this to get familiar with the concept of npm packages: https://nodesource.com/blog/an-absolute-beginners-guide-to-using-npm/

So to answer your question: There will be no issue because of `npm install`, you can go ahead.